# Connecting esp8266 to AWS IoT

Tags: arduino, esp8266, aws-iot

I am trying to connect a WeMos D1 mini based on ESP8266 to the Amazon Web Service AWS IoT using https://github.com/heskew/aws-sdk-arduino.

However, when I flash the device, I get a 403 back, with the following message:
"Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api'. "

Changing

```
this->awsService = "iotdata";
```

to

```
this->awsService = "execute-api";
```

in *AmazonIOTClient.cpp* results in a 404:
"No method found matching route things/my-thing/shadow for http method POST."
and, according to [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=689483) the service should be 'iotdata' for the request to succeed.

Has someone had the same problem and figured out a way to get it running? If so, help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here the full code for the example:

```
#include <AmazonIOTClient.h>
#include <Esp8266AWSImplementations.h>
#include <AWSFoundationalTypes.h>
#include "keys.h"

const int sleepTimeS = 30;

void printWiFiData();
void printCurrentNetwork();
void publish(const char *topic, String data);
void publishToAWS();

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Started!");

  publishToAWS();
  ESP.deepSleep(sleepTimeS * 1000000);
}

void loop() {
}

void printWiFiData() {

  // IP address
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // MAC address
  byte mac[6];
  WiFi.macAddress(mac);
  Serial.print("MAC address: ");
  Serial.print(mac[5], HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[4], HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[3], HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[2], HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(mac[1], HEX);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(mac[0], HEX);
}

void printCurrentNetwork() {

  // SSID
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // signal strength:
  Serial.print("signal strength (RSSI): ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());
}

void publish(const char *topic, String data) {

  AmazonIOTClient iotClient;
  ActionError actionError;

  Esp8266HttpClient httpClient;
  Esp8266DateTimeProvider dateTimeProvider;

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(wifiSsid);
  Serial.println("...");

  WiFi.begin(wifiSsid, wifiPwd);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(50);
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  printCurrentNetwork();
  printWiFiData();

  delay(50);

  Serial.println("Initializing IoT client...");

  iotClient.setAWSRegion(awsIotRegion);
  iotClient.setAWSEndpoint(awsIotEndpoint);
  iotClient.setAWSDomain(awsIotDomain);
  iotClient.setAWSPath("/things/my-thing/shadow");
  iotClient.setAWSKeyID(awsKeyID);
  iotClient.setAWSSecretKey(awsSecKey);
  iotClient.setHttpClient(&httpClient);
  iotClient.setDateTimeProvider(&dateTimeProvider);

  delay(50);

  Serial.println("Updating thing shadow...");

  MinimalString shadow = ("{\"state\":{\"reported\":{\"text\":" + data + "}}}").c_str();
  char* result = iotClient.update_shadow(shadow, actionError);

  Serial.print("result: ");
  Serial.println(result);
}

void publishToAWS() {

  Serial.println("Publishing to AWS IoT Broker");

  publish("my-thing/text", "Hello World!");
}
```

*keys.cpp* file:

```
#include "keys.h"

// AWS User Credentials
const char* awsKeyID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
const char* awsSecKey = "X1xxx23xxxxXXXX34XXxxxxX56xXxxxxxxXx789x";

// AWS IoT
const char* awsIotRegion = "eu-central-1";
const char* awsIotEndpoint = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
const char* awsIotDomain = "iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";

// Init and connect WiFi to local WLAN
char* wifiSsid = "mySSID";
char* wifiPwd = "password";
```

Answer (score 3):

I can finally contribute something :)

I got this very same example working a few days ago. However I used the same library just a different branch [iot-get-shadow-and-cleanup](https://github.com/heskew/aws-sdk-arduino/tree/iot-get-shadow-and-cleanup). I don't recall having to make any changes as the one you mentioned:

`this->awsService = "iotdata";` to `this->awsService = "execute-api";`

Here are the correct settings for your AWS endpoint that goes into keys.cpp

```
  awsIotRegion = "us-east-1";
  awsIotEndpoint = "amazonaws.com";
  awsIotDomain = "axxxxs2pxxxrlx.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";`
```

Also add `delete[] result;` to the end of the `publish()` to save some precious heap space.

I would recommend using the iot-get-shadow-and-cleanup branch since it has fixes for memory leaks.

I made one more change to resolve all issues with running out of heap space when updating the shadow continiously. In AWSClient4.cpp I changed `// delete[] server;` to `delete[] data;` - I am not 100% sure if this was necessary but combined with the addition of `delete[] result;` I was able to update the shadown every minute continuously for an hour without loosing any heap.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, changing the settings in the keys.cpp file as you suggested did not fix the problem (now I don't even get a response back from the server), even when using the  iot-get-shadow-and-cleanup branch. Thank you for the help though!